# Javascript object losing properties after assignment

Tags: javascript, properties, module

This is probably a nuance of JS, but if I understood why it happens, then I can maybe come up with a workaround.  I need to be able to access object "a" and its properties, which are assigned in function f1().  However, the properties are gone when trying to access them.  Also, why does prop1 of object "b" = 1 instead of 100?

```
function Obj(){

    var a = {};
    var b = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
    var c = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

    var f1 = function(){
        a = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

        // in real life this calls a function that returns an object
        // a = someOtherFunctionThatReturnsAnObject();
    };

    var f2 = function(){
        b = { prop1: 100, prop2: 200 };
    };

    var vm = {
        f1:f1,
        f2:f2,
        a:a,
        b:b,
        c:c
    };
    return vm;
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.f1();
obj.f2();

alert (obj.a.prop1);   // undefined
alert (obj.b.prop1);   // 1   * Why not 100? *
alert (obj.c.prop1);   // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a scope problem, which I'm having difficulties with to explain. The object vm gets assigned a b and c. (and the functions). But the functions update the local variables var a,b,c. Not the variables located in the vm object.

(like I said.. hard time explaining)

But this is how it works..

```
function Obj(){
    var vm = this; //Or var vm = {};
    vm.a = {};
    vm.b = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
    vm.c = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

    vm.f1 = function(){
        vm.a = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

        // in real life this calls a function that returns an object
        // a = someOtherFunctionThatReturnsAnObject();
    };

    vm.f2 = function(){
        vm.b = { prop1: 100, prop2: 200 };
    };


    return vm;
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.f1();
obj.f2();
```

Comment: I'm modifying existing code that uses vars everywhere, instead of "this".  The current code is similar to example 'c' above where the assignment is made when declared, and didn't change.  That seems to work but not flexible at all.  Now I need to be dynamic and change what these objects are pointing to.   This is just a simple snippet.  The module is large so re-writing it to your approach may not be feasible.  Unless that's all I can do.  thanks

Comment: This gives the expected behavior, but a few things to point out:  1) The commented code `var vm = {};` will not work.  2) `return vm;` is not needed.  3) You could remove `var vm = this;` and replace each instance of `vm` with the word, `this`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/be2o3x69/

Comment: There's no scoping problem, there is however a problem with overwriting references.

Comment: 1) var vm = {} does work... as long as you return vm :) (which also answer 2)

3) And i kept the vm assignment to keep it concise it with the question. 

But thanks for the feedback :)

@beije. Thanks, you explained it much better!

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely correct about the commented code working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're overwriting the references in the methods f1 and f2.

```
function Obj(){

    var a = {};
    var b = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
    var c = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

    var f1 = function(){
        a = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }; /* <-- Overwriting the reference with a new object */

        // in real life this calls a function that returns an object
        // a = someOtherFunctionThatReturnsAnObject();
    };

    var f2 = function(){
        b = { prop1: 100, prop2: 200 }; /* <-- Overwriting the reference with a new object */
    };

    var vm = {
        f1:f1, /* <-- Passing reference */
        f2:f2, /* <-- Passing reference */
        a:a, /* <-- Passing reference */
        b:b, /* <-- Passing reference */
        c:c /* <-- Passing reference */
    };
    return vm;
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.f1();
obj.f2();

alert (obj.a.prop1);   // undefined
alert (obj.b.prop1);   // 1   * Why not 100? *
alert (obj.c.prop1);   // 1
```

To get the behaviour that you want, you need to change the value on the reference.

```
var f2 = function(){
    b.prop1 = 100; /* Changing the value on the referenced object */
    b.prop2 = 200; /* Changing the value on the referenced object */
};
```

And here's how to prove it.

Your current solution, if you return the object b from the method f2 and then check it against the obj.b property, they will be different objects

```
var f2 = function(){
    b = { prop1: 100, prop2: 200 }; /* <-- Overwriting the reference with a new object */
    return b;
};
[...]
alert (obj.b === obj.f2()); // False, not the same object
```

If you instead change the properties on the obj.b object, they will be the same.

```
var f2 = function(){
    b.prop1 = 100;
    b.prop2 = 200;
    return b;
};
[...]
alert (obj.b === obj.f2()); // True, the identical object
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing this from scratch, I'd do it like `this`:

```js
function Obj(){
    this.a = {};
    this.b = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
    this.c = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

    this.f1 = function(){
      this.a = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
    };

    this.f2 = function(){
      this.b = { prop1: 100, prop2: 200 };
    };
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.f1();
obj.f2();

alert (obj.a.prop1);   // 1
alert (obj.b.prop1);   // 100
alert (obj.c.prop1);   // 1
```

However, since you have so much code to change, you could simply add `this` to the variables within the functions:

```js
function Obj(){
    var a = {};
    var b = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
    var c = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };

    var f1 = function(){
        this.a = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
    };

    var f2 = function(){
        this.b = { prop1: 100, prop2: 200 };
    };

    var vm = {
        f1:f1,
        f2:f2,
        a:a,
        b:b,
        c:c
    };
    return vm;
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.f1();
obj.f2();

alert (obj.a.prop1);   // 1
alert (obj.b.prop1);   // 100
alert (obj.c.prop1);   // 1
```